# Cloudflare service worker code to "Bypass cache on cookie" not working

Tags: service-worker, cloudflare

I wrote this code as a Cloudflare Service Worker which is meant to precisely emulate their native function for "Bypass cache on cookie". Specifically, if someone has a Wordpress cookie - it would bypass cache, otherwise it does not.

It does not seem to function at all - in that despite having a cookie and being logged in (confirmed via Chrome developer tools) - I still get a Cloudflare cache HIT on this example domain - [Tallyfy](https://tallyfy.com). Anything wrong with it? Help appreciated!

```
// A Service Worker which skips cache if the request contains a cookie.
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
let request = event.request;

var flag=false;
if(request.headers.cookie)   {

var pairs = request.headers.cookie.split(";");
var patt = new RegExp("wp-.*|wordpress.*|comment_.*|woocommerce_.*")


for(var i=0;i<pairs.length;i++){
  if(patt.test(pairs[i])){
      flag = true;
      break;
  }
}

}

  if (request.headers.has('Cookie') && flag) {
    // Cookie present. Add Cache-Control: no-cache.
    let newHeaders = new Headers(request.headers)
    newHeaders.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
    event.respondWith(fetch(request, {headers: newHeaders}))
  }
  // Use default behavior.
  return
})
```

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution? If yes can you share with us please? Thank you :)

Comment: @FrancescoLoddo Cloudflare confirmed that it's not possible to intercept and cache to the client yet.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, i follow this guide: https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cloudflare-workers/#whatitlookslike and it doesn't works :(

Answer (score 1):

try this and let me know

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  let request = event.request
  var flag = false;
  if (request.headers.has('Cookie')) {
    var cookie = request.headers.get('Cookie');
    pairs = cookie.split(";");
    var patt = new RegExp("wordpress_logged_in.*|wp_woocommerce_session.*");
    for(var i=0;i<pairs.length;i++){
      if(patt.test(pairs[i])){
          flag = true;
          break;
      }
    }
    console.log(flag);
    if (request.headers.has('Cookie') && flag) {
      let newHeaders = new Headers(request.headers)
      newHeaders.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
      newHeaders.set('Pragma', 'no-cache')
      event.respondWith(fetch(request, {headers: newHeaders}))
    }
    // Use default behavior.
    return;
  }
})
```

Comment: It worked for me, I could simulate bypass cache on cookie functionality with this code in my worker. Thanks